# Paths layers disappear on map after saving in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-3, path

I am quite new to GIS. I am working on a historical map with three sets of points. When I create a path between those points with the "Points to Path" tool (via Ctrl+Alt+T), it shows up nicely.

However, when I save the map and open it again later, the paths layers are still visible in the layer toolbar, but no longer visible on the map, not even when I click "Zoom to map layer". I am working in QGIS 3.2 (Bonn).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Like most tools in QGIS, "Points to Path" creates a **temporary** layer by default.

Temporary layers only exist while the QGIS project is open. If you close and re-open the project, all the features in a temporary layer are deleted. Only the layer name and style settings are saved.

You should instead **Save to File**. Then it will save the output as a shapefile (or other format that you choose).

[image]

If you already have a temporary layer, you can right click on the layer name and choose "Export" (in older versions of QGIS, choose "Save as..."). This is useful if you aren't sure you'll want to save the tool output. You can run the tool multiple times with different parameters, and only save the outputs that you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this worked perfectly. I should have asked my question here much earlier!